Помогите с SQL- запросом к таблице
Только начинаю разбираться с базами данных. Есть субд MariaDb с таблицами. Данные дёргаются php скриптом с привлечением библиотеки RedBean.
Там есть метод для выборки R::getAll(). Помогите составить SQL запрос для таблиц с реляцией. Ниже таблицы из бд.
>>>|maintable|<<<

id  |   phone|  organizationKey |   podrazdelenieKey|   doljnostKey |   serialnumber    |   invnumber   |   primechanie

1       2392 |      114         |        225        |       333     |       sn123456    |   inv123456   |   comment...2392
2       2659 |      113         |        224        |       333     |       sn155456    |   inv123443   |   comment...2659  
3       2680 |      114         |        224        |       335     |       sn166456    |   inv124356   |   comment...2680  
4       2681 |      114         |        224        |       334     |       sn127756    |   inv123456   |   comment...2681  
5       2753 |      114         |        222        |       333     |       sn432456    |   inv123456   |   comment...2753  
6       2789 |      113         |        225        |       333     |       sn134456    |   inv433456   |   comment...2789  
7       2825 |      114         |        224        |       335     |       sn223456    |   inv125456   |   comment...2825  
8       2826 |      113         |        225        |       336     |       sn126656    |   inv177456   |   comment...2826  
9       2876 |      113         |        222        |       336     |       sn426656    |   inv199956   |   comment...2876  
10      2885 |      114         |        224        |       336     |       sn123436    |   inv127756   |   comment...2885  


_____________________________________________________________

        >>>|orgtable|<<<

id  |       organization                | IDorganization 

1   |       organization_odin           |   111         
2   |       organization_dva            |   112 
3   |       organization_tri            |   113         
4   |       organization_chetire        |   114 

_____________________________________________________________

        >>>|podrazdeltable|<<<

id  |       podrazdelenie               |   IDpodrazdeleniya 

1   |       podrazdelenie_odin          |   222         
2   |       podrazdelenie_dva           |   223 
3   |       podrazdelenie_tri           |   224         
4   |       podrazdelenie_chetire       |   225 

_____________________________________________________________

        >>>|doljnosttable|<<<

id  |       doljnost                |   IDdoljnosti 

1   |       doljnost_odin           |   333         
2   |       doljnost_dva            |   334 
3   |       doljnost_tri            |   335         
4   |       doljnost_chetire        |   336 

Как видно, в главной таблице maintable есть  поля organizationKey, podrazdelenieKey, doljnostKey. Они ссылаются на другие таблицы - orgtable, podrazdeltable, doljnosttable соответсвенно. Метод R::getAll() формирует массив на выходе. Вот такой массив.
[0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [phone] => 2392
            [serialnumber] => sn123456 
            [invnumber] => inv123456
            [primechanie] => comment...2392
            [organizationKey] => 114
            [podrazdelenieKey] => 225
            [doljnostKey] => 333
            [organization] => organization_chetire
            [podrazdelenie] => podrazdelenie_dva
            [doljnost] => doljnost_odin
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [phone] => 2659
            [serialnumber] => sn155456 
            [invnumber] => inv123443
            [primechanie] => comment...2659
            [organizationKey] => 113
            [podrazdelenieKey] => 224
            [doljnostKey] => 333
            [organization] => organization_tri
            [podrazdelenie] => podrazdelenie_tri
            [doljnost] => doljnost_odin
        )

SQL запрос выглядит так (пока громоздкий):
    R::getAll(
            "SELECT *,
                    `maintable`.`id`,
                    `maintable`.`phone`,
                    `maintable`.`serialnumber`,
                    `maintable`.`invnumber`,
                    `maintable`.`primechanie`
             FROM `maintable` 
             LEFT JOIN orgtable ON `maintable`.`organizationKey`=`orgtable`.`id`
             LEFT JOIN podrazdeltable ON `maintable`.`podrazdelenieKey`=`podrazdeltable`.`id`
             LEFT JOIN doljnosttable ON `maintable`.`doljnostKey`=`doljnosttable`.`id`
             ORDER BY `maintable`.`id` ASC LIMIT 2" );


Как мне сделать sql запрос, чтобы в массиве не было organizationKey, podrazdelenieKey, doljnostKey и primechanie ? Сейчас, как видно, в SELECT стоит звезда, что означает вывести все записи. Но как ограничить их, и чтобы в массиве остались только читабельные и нужные мне названия (такие как [podrazdelenie] => podrazdelenie_dva, которые в полях доп таблиц).На выходе вот такой массив чтобы  получился (для эконимии места указал один элемент массива)

[0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [phone] => 2392
            [serialnumber] => sn123456 
            [invnumber] => inv123456
            [organization] => organization_chetire
            [podrazdelenie] => podrazdelenie_dva
            [doljnost] => doljnost_odin
        )
...

Т.е. из главной таблицы взяли несколько значений (не все), и из дополнительных таблиц названия полей и читабельные значения.
п.с. индексы в таблицах настроены

Сейчас, как видно, в SELECT стоит звезда, что означает вывести все записи. Но как ограничить их, и чтобы в массиве остались только читабельные и нужные мне названия По-моему, очевидно, что надо стереть звезду, а вместо неё записать (только) те поля, которые требуется получить, с указанием, из каких таблиц брать поля. Вот точно так же, как после этой звезды идёт дополнением список из 5 полей из таблицы maintable

спасибо за наводку, затупил, всё понял, сделал - получилось.
